# Excel Userform accelerator key for a label doesn't work

Tags: excel, label, userform, acceleratorkey

I have a userform in my macro.  I replaced the ActiveX buttons with a label.  Each ActiveX button had an accelerator key and they all worked like as expected.  Once I changed the ActiveX buttons to labels, the accelerator keys no longer worked with the labels.  I'm not sure.  I'd appreciate any suggestions to get the accelerator keys working again.  Thanks for the help

Comment: What do you mean they don't work? If you put an accelerator key on a label, the next control in the tab order (that can get the focus) will get the focus. Is that not happening? What is the next control in the tab order?

Comment: @ Dick Kuseika........when the user hits Alt + A nothing happens like it did before.when I used buttons instead of lables.  The next control is another label.  There are a number of frames, textboxes and labels within this userform.  Thanks

Comment: I imagine that it sees that the next control is a label and since that can't take the focus, does nothing. What do you want it to do? Why did you change from commandbuttons to labels?

Comment: @ Dick Kusleika...........User's started to have issues when pushing ActiveX buttons.  Someone suggested changing all of the ActiveX buttons to shapes or labels.  Turns out it was an IT policy that caused this issue.  I've only heard from 1 user that they like to use the accelerator key.  When the accelerator key is used (or label is pushed) it kicks off a subroutine that moves the data from the userform to one of the sheets in the macro.  Thanks..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of the Accelerator property of a Label control is to set the focus to the next control in the tab order. The behavior of the Accelerator of a commandbutton is to call its Click event. You can't call a Label's click event, or any other event, from an accelerator key.

If you want to use labels, you could put textboxes after the labels and put whatever code you want in the Textbox_Enter event.  I created two labels and two textboxes. I made the Height and Width of each textbox 1, so they are almost invisible. When the accelerator for the label was pressed, the focus went to the textbox and the Enter even fired.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()

    'do the thing the button would do

End Sub
```

A bit of a hack and a little extra set up, but it works.

Comment: @ Dick Kusleika.........Thanks for the information.  I ended up changing the labels back to ActiveX buttons and the Accelerator key is working again.  I appreciate the information and will keep in mind for the future